# Xamarin.Forms Background Service prevent to start when app is running

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I managed to implement my Background Service which works really good. The Service connects to my WebSocket and keeps the connection alive after the App is closed.

I'm starting the Background Service when the App closes so that I can reconnect to the Backend, but I want to be able to close the Service so the App can now take care of the Connection.

I've tried Flags, Events, and other conditions to Stop the Service when the App starts but the Service Starts no matter what.

Is it possible to stop the Service when the App runs, so that the App can handle the Connection?

MainActivity.cs

```
    [Activity(Label = "App",
              Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher",
              Theme = "@style/splashscreen",
              MainLauncher = true,
              ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App());
            StartBackgroundService();
            IsAppRunning = true;
        }

        private void StartBackgroundService() {
            StopService = false;
            RealtimeService.StopServiceEventHandler += StopServiceEventHandler;
            StartService(new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(BackgroundRealtimeService)));
        }

        private void StopServiceEventHandler(object sender, object o) {
            if (StopService) {
                StopService(new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(BackgroundRealtimeService)));
            }
        }


        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            IsAppRunning = false;
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

BackgroundRealtimeService.cs

```
[Service]
    public class BackgroundRealtimeService : Service
    {
        public async void Initialize() {

           // Service Code

        }


        public override void OnCreate() {
            base.OnCreate();
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId) {

            new Task(Initialize).Start();
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }


        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are always starting the service in the `OnCreate` override, call `StopService` instead.

Comment: I'm starting the service with a flag in ondestroy when the app get killed. I did try that but that didn't work.

Comment: ? But you are **always** starting the service in `OnCreate`, from your question, you never want that, right? So call `StopService` instead.

Comment: Ok I will try to call stopservice thanks

Comment: Is there a way to start a Service when the app closes because currently, i need to start it in onCreate and on onDestroy in setting a flag so that the code can begin to execute